# Find the average for user-defined window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, binning

I have a pandas dataframe that has raw heart rate data with the index of time (in seconds).

I am trying to bin the data so that I can have the average of a user define window (e.g. 10s) - not a rolling average, just an average of 10s, then the 10s following, etc.

```
import pandas as pd

hr_raw = pd.read_csv('hr_data.csv', index_col='time')
print(hr_raw)

      heart_rate
time            
0.6        164.0
1.0        182.0
1.3        164.0
1.6        150.0
2.0        152.0
2.4        141.0
2.9        163.0
3.2        141.0
3.7        124.0
4.2        116.0
4.7        126.0
5.1        116.0
5.7        107.0
```

Using the example data above, I would like to be able to set a user defined window size (let's use 2 seconds) and produce a new dataframe that has index of 2sec increments and averages the 'heart_rate' values if the time falls into that window (and should continue to the end of the dataframe).

For example:

```
      heart_rate
time            
2.0        162.40
4.0        142.25
6.0        116.25
```

I can only seem to find methods to bin the data based on a predetermined number of bins (e.g. making a histogram) and this only returns the count/frequency.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `groupby` should do it.

```
df.groupby((df.index // 2 + 1) * 2).mean()

      heart_rate
time            
2.0       165.00
4.0       144.20
6.0       116.25
```

Note that the reason for the *slight* difference between our answers is that the upper bound is excluded. That means, a reading taken at 2.0s will be considered for the 4.0s time interval. This is how it is usually done, a similar solution with the `TimeGrouper` will yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Like coldspeed pointed out, 2s will be considered in 4s, however, if you need it in 2x bucket, you can

```
In [1038]: df.groupby(np.ceil(df.index/2)*2).mean()
Out[1038]:
      heart_rate
time
2.0       162.40
4.0       142.25
6.0       116.25
```